# Talend combine two different data flows with same schema into one

Tags: talend

I am using talend 6.1.1 and i am i have two components tmysqlinput and tfixedflowinput.

Schema is same for both the components and i am trying to combine the data generated by these components.

```
for example: schema is like col1 and col2
output of tmysqlinput component is: 
1,2
2,3
output of tixeflowinput component is: 
3,4
4,5
```

Now output which i am expeting is like combination of both the ouputs.
It should be like:

```
1,2
2,3
3,4
4,5
```

Please help me to combine the outputs of those two components.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to using tUnite is tHashOutput.

For example:

```
tMySqlInput--main-->tHashOutput
    |
 onSubjobOK
    |
tFixedFlowInput--main-->tHashOutput
    |
 onSubjobOK
    |
tHashInput--main-->tFileOuputDelimtited
```

In the second tHashOutput, make sure to associate it with the first tHashOutput.

In the tHashInput, make sure to associate it with the first tHashOutput.

tUnite would generally be preferred, but depending upon the case tHashOutput can be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

If the schema is exactly the same, you can send the row output of both components into a tUnite component

https://help.talend.com/display/TalendComponentsReferenceGuide54EN/tUnite

Comment: I find that sometimes there are differences in the schema a if the two flows which are hard to spot. To make it more likely to work, define a schema in the metadata repository. Then use that metadata schema in output of the components which would feed into tUnite and in tUnite itself .